# Update fxml tag when state changes

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to create some kind of 'security' fxml tag that disables / makes invisible its children depending on the state of some kind of SecurityManager class.

The difficulty I have is the following. When the state of the SecurityManager class changes I want all the securityTags to update their visible property. Granted, I can, everytime the tag constructor is called, add all SecurityTag nodes to a static list and loop over it when the SecurityManger class changes state. But then, what if a security tag node gets removed from a parent? How do I get rid of it in the list? Or maybe there is just an allround better way to deal with this?

```
public class SecurityTag extends Pane {

    public Security() {
        super();
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

```
public class SecurityManager {

    private boolean authorized;

    public SecurityManager() {
        this.authorized = false;
    }

    public void login() {
        this.authorized = true;
    }

    public void logout() {
        this.authorized = false;
    }

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorized;
    }

}
```

Comment: The standard pattern for this functionality is called “Model-View-Controller”, or MVC. There are several variants. The basic idea is to implement your `SecurityManager` class using a JavaFX `BooleanProperty` for `authorized` and then bind the visible property of the nodes to it. See, maybe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx

Comment: The problem, maybe I am too strict about this, with this approach is that I need to add javaFx functionality in my SecurityManager class which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: At worst, you’d use JavaFX properties, which have nothing to do with UI code in any way. You could also use standard Java beans with property change listeners, and use a `JavaBeanBooleanProperty` as an interface between the `SecurityManager` and UI code.

Comment: unrelated: don't extend a layout if you don't add any layout-related functionality

Comment: As a slight curiosity, you can do this with CSS. Add a style class (e.g. `.privleged`) to any control that needs authorization. Create a custom CSS `PseudoClass` (e.g. `authorized`) and simply set/unset it on the root node of your UI when the user logs in/out. Then just use the rules `.privileged { visibility: false ; }` and `.root:authorized .privileged { visibility: visible }` in your external CSS file. That way, only the root node needs updating in any way when the security manager changes state, and you avoid unnecessary subclassing of `Pane`, which has a number of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to make the `authorized` property in your `SecurityManager` a JavaFX property:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;

public class SecurityManager {

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper authorized ;

    public SecurityManager() {
        this.authorized = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false) ;
    }



    public void login() {
        this.authorized.set(true);
    }

    public void logout() {
        this.authorized.set(false);
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty authorizedProperty() {
        return authorized.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorizedProperty().get();
    }

}
```

Now you can simply bind the relevant properties to the `authorized` property of the `SecurityManager`. Depending on the property you're binding, you can do this directly in FXML or in the controller. You can make a `SecurityManager` instance available to the FXML file by placing it in the `FXMLLoader`'s `namespace`, and make it available to the controller simply by passing it as a parameter to the controller constructor, and setting the controller manually (i.e. not using the `fx:controller` attribute) on the `FXMLLoader`.

Here's an example FXML file. Note how the "Privileged Action" button binds its visibility to the security manager with

```
visible = "${securityManager.authorized}"
```

You could also do

```
disable = "${ !securityManager.authorized}"
```

if you preferred just to disable it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane ?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label ?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <Label fx:id = "securityStatus"></Label>
    </top>
    <center>
        <VBox spacing="5" fillWidth="true">
            <Button text="Regular Action" maxWidth="Infinity"></Button>
            <Button text="Privileged Action" visible = "${securityManager.authorized}" maxWidth="Infinity"></Button>

            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" left="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <left>
        <VBox spacing="5" fillWidth="true">
            <Button text="login" onAction="#login" maxWidth="Infinity"/>
            <Button text="logout" onAction="#logout" maxWidth="Infinity"/>

            <padding>
                <Insets top="5" left="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
            </padding>
        </VBox>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Here's a controller. The text of the label is bound to the state of the security manager using a more complex binding than can be achieved in FXML:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SecurityController {

    private final SecurityManager securityManager ;

    @FXML
    private Label securityStatus ;

    public SecurityController(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        this.securityManager = securityManager ;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        securityStatus.textProperty().bind(Bindings
            .when(securityManager.authorizedProperty())
            .then("Logged In")
            .otherwise("Logged Out")
        );
    }

    @FXML
    private void login() {
        securityManager.login();
    }

    @FXML
    private void logout() {
        securityManager.logout();
    }
}
```

And finally, here's how it is all assembled:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SecurityApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecurityExample.fxml"));
        loader.getNamespace().put("securityManager", securityManager);
        loader.setController(new SecurityController(securityManager));

        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that this approach avoids any unnecessary subclassing of JavaFX nodes (e.g. `Pane`), which can lead to issues (for example, you may want to place security-dependent nodes in an existing layout pane, and this makes is more difficult to use standard layouts).

---

If, as suggested in the comments, you want the `SecurityManager` class to be agnostic to JavaFX (and presumably desktop Java in general), you could simply create a delegate for the UI which uses JavaFX properties, and arrange for it to be updated when the "real" security manager is updated.

E.g. here's a `SecurityManager` that implements a classical "listener" pattern:

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface AuthorizationListener {
    void authorizationChanged(boolean newStatus);
}
```

and

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecurityManager  {

    private boolean authorized ;
    private final List<AuthorizationListener> listeners ;

    public SecurityManager() {
        this.listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void login() {
        setAuthorized(true);
    }

    public void logout() {
        setAuthorized(false);
    }

    public void addListener(AuthorizationListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(AuthorizationListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorized;
    }

    private void setAuthorized(boolean authorized) {
        if (! this.authorized == authorized) {
            this.authorized = authorized ;
            listeners.forEach(l -> l.authorizationChanged(authorized));
        }
    }

}
```

Note these are completely agnostic with respect to any view technology.

Now you can create a "UI security manager delegate":

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper;

public class UISecurityDelegate  {

    private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper authorized ;

    private final SecurityManager manager ;

    public UISecurityDelegate(SecurityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager ;
        this.authorized = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(manager.isAuthorized()) ;
        manager.addListener(authorized::set);
    }

    public void login() {
        manager.login();
    }
    public void logout() {
        manager.logout();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty authorizedProperty() {
        return authorized.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public boolean isAuthorized() {
        return authorizedProperty().get();
    }

}
```

And finally update the UI code with

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class SecurityController {

    private final UISecurityDelegate securityManager ;

    @FXML
    private Label securityStatus ;

    public SecurityController(UISecurityDelegate securityManager) {
        this.securityManager = securityManager ;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        securityStatus.textProperty().bind(Bindings
            .when(securityManager.authorizedProperty())
            .then("Logged In")
            .otherwise("Logged Out")
        );
    }

    @FXML
    private void login() {
        securityManager.login();
    }

    @FXML
    private void logout() {
        securityManager.logout();
    }
}
```

and

```
package org.jamesd.examples.security;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SecurityApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // probably created by data or service layer, etc:
        SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager();

        UISecurityDelegate securityDelegate = new UISecurityDelegate(securityManager) ;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecurityExample.fxml"));
        loader.getNamespace().put("securityManager", securityDelegate);
        loader.setController(new SecurityController(securityDelegate));

        Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer.